# OneToOne cannot compose a file for liquibase in case of two-way communication

Tags: java, liquibase

I am studying the topic of linking tables.
While I'm dealing with OneToOne.
The Person table was reduced in order to save space. It is clear that one name will not be able to unambiguously indicate a specific person.

The first option is one-way communication
A person has an INN and he can have only one. And each TIN is linked to a specific person and there can also be only one, but we do not need to store information about its owner in the INN database.

Person.java:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons", schema = "date")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name; 

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "inn_id", unique = true)
    private InnBase innBase;
}
```

InnBase.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "inn_base", schema = "date")
public class InnBase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "inn_number")
    private int innNumber;
}
```

file for liquibase

```
<changeSet id="create_person" author="alex">
    <createTable tableName="person" schemaName="date">
        <column name="id" type="BIGINT" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>       
        <column name="name" type="VARCHAR(255)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="id_inn" type="INT">
            <constraints nullable="false" foreignKeyName="fk_inn" referencedTableSchemaName="date"
                         referencedTableName="types" referencedColumnNames="id"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="create_inn" author="alex">
    <createTable tableName="inn_base" schemaName="date">
        <column name="id" type="BIGINT" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="inn_number" type="VARCHAR(255)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

The second option is two-way communication.

A person has an INN and he can have only one. A specific person is tied to each INN and there can also be only one. But we need to be able to find the INN of its owner.
In this case, you need to change the InnBase class.

Person.java:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name; 

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "inn_id", unique = true)
    private InnBase innBase;
}
```

InnBase.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class InnBase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "inn_number")
    private int innNumber;
    
    @OneToOne (optional=false, mappedBy="innBase", fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
    private Person owner;
}
```

How much did I understand this topic correctly?

And tell me how I need to change the liquibase file for the int_base table in the second case.

I understand that in the second case it is necessary to create a third table for communication:

```
id | person_id | int_id
```

But then how can the entity code change?

Created tables via hibernate. And it turned out that for the second option, the structure of the tables has not changed at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are describing is really just a change in the hibernate mapping and doesn't impact the way it's stored in the database and therefore doesn't impact what your Liquibase changelog would be.

In both cases, you have a one-to-one correspondence between person and inn_base, with a foreign key from person to inn_base.

With the 2nd case, you also have a person attribute on your object, but that is just hibernate handling the query to the person table also from a call to InnBase instead of just a query to the inn_base table from your Person object.

Am I understanding that correctly?

If you changed your model so that instead of having a person->inn_base foreign key to model your one-to-one mapping you made an inn_base->person foreign key, then you'd need to change your hibernate mapping and change your liqubiase changelog to define the different columns and foreign keys. But so far you haven't done that.